# Screaming frog crawling, images, JS and CSS files as well

Tags: seo, javascript, noindex, screaming-frog

When I plug in my website URL in the free version of Screaming frog, it also lists the images, CSS and JS files. Is it suppose to be like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Screaming Frog crawls images, CSS and JS, but there are configuration items to turn off crawling them.  See [SEO Spider Configuration | Screaming Frog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/user-guide/configuration/)  The settings are located in the "Spider Crawl" tab of the configuration.